# Best way to schedule jobs so as to get minimum average turnaround time

Tags: optimization, scheduling

The question is right there above.

Comment: Hint: if you think you can fit your whole question in the title, that means you've not done enough research to even get to grips with the basics.

Comment: This question can not be answered without a lot more detail. All answers between "greedy is optimal" and "NP-complete would be fun compared to this" are possible!

Answer (score 1):

This is an open question, there's no universal one-size-fits all solution (yet?). The goal of **all** scheduling algorithms is to try to minimize turnaround time of all jobs.

The best scheduling algorithm (i.e. the one that minimized turnaround time) is dependant on the statistics of the jobs. Their start times, their durations, how accurately a heuristic can preempt them, etc. *If there was a universally optimal algorithm that guarantees minimized turnaround time, why would we ever use anything else?*

Consider the case of SJF, and it's minimum average waiting time. We don't really care about the waiting time of jobs, so much as how the waiting time is a *heuristic* for turnaround time. Other algorithms use other heuristics to try to try to minimize turnaround time.